# How is the var.pred field in ar routine computed?

Tags: r

Let's say I have a time series data stored in a variable called `x`. After running

```
x.ar <- ar(x, order.max = 100)
```

The returned object has a `var.pred` field representing "the prediction variance" according to the help file. I am wondering what is the algorithm to compute `var.pred` in an object returned by `ar` command in R?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Ye

Comment: Type `ar` into console and follow the white rabbit.

Comment: The tag [ar] is for the UNIX archive utility; I'm not sure there's a tag for the R command, but that one's not it, so I removed it.